# Adjective to describe an overpowering odor

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to describe an overpowering odor comparable to *deafening* for an overpowering noise?

> That strong, loud noise is deafening.
>
> That strong, pungent odor is ____.

It may be that there is no equivalent word.  But surely some have encountered an overpowering odor.  What is that action called?

Comment: Welcome to English Language SE and thank you for your question. I edited your question to remove instances of “overpowered by an odor”, since this does not seem to be exactly what you are looking for. Please check that everything is still according to your intentions and feel free to [edit] if it isn’t.

Comment: Of the five basic senses *(sight, hearing, touch, taste, smell),* we have specific words for loss of three *(blinded, deafened, numbed)*.  But I don't think there are equivalents for the other two - and I suffered the misery of being [XXXX'ed by Lamisil](http://www.sterishoe.com/foot-care-blog/toenail-fungus-treatments/lamisil-side-effects-may-include-permanent-taste-loss/) for months (made even worse by the fear that it might be *permanent*). With all my scouring of the Net for advice at the time, I think I'd have noticed if there'd been any such word.

Comment: [Other adjectives related to stench](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/stench)

    bad
    feculent
    fulsome
    high

    caprylic
    fetid
    fusty
    jumentous

    corky
    foul
    graveolent
    maleolent

    empyreumatic
    frowzy
    halitotic
    malodorous

Comment: The word **anosmia** ([from Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/anosmia)) is the noun for absence of the sense of smell, but I don't think there's verb for causing anosmia.

Comment: While eyesight and hearing are senses which can be dulled or damaged by an overly intense stimulus, the same isn't true of senses such as taste or sense of smell.  It really isn't possible to have an odor so strong as to damage one's olfactory system.  An odor can be intense to the point of being unpleasant or painful, but it can't really be intense to the point of losing one's sense of smell the way sights and sounds can be intense to the point of causing blindness or deafness.

Comment: @Dr.Funk - Though it is true that a strong odor will decrease one's sensitivity to similar odors for a time

Comment: Sure, but nose-blindness is specific to a given odor, and doesn't reduce one's sensitivity to all odors.  A similar phenomenon can occur with images and sounds, where you cease to notice images that you see all the time, or cease to perceive sounds that you hear all the time.  This doesn't mean that you're actually blind or deaf to them.  It simply means that your brain has tuned them out because it deems them to be unimportant.  This isn't really the kind of phenomenon we're talking about with a blinding light or a deafening sound, which are so intense that they impair the senses.

Comment: "Nose-blindness" would not be analogous to deafness in this context.

Answer (score 2):

May not be an exact counterpart of *deafening*, but ***suffocating*** may help. If a loud sound can be uncomfortable by being *deafening*, a strong smell can be uncomfortable by being *suffocating*.

> That strong, pungent odor is ***suffocating***.

ODO:

> **[suffocate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/suffocate)**
>   *VERB*
>
> **1.1** Have or cause to have difficulty in breathing
>
> ‘Scheele described the chlorine gas formed as having a greenish yellow
>   color and a suffocating odor ‘most oppressive to the lungs.’’

Answer (score 1):

I have not heard anyone call a noise 'overpowering'.  The word people use for overwhelming noise is *deafening*.

If a smell is overwhelming the usual response is to say it is  ***[overpowering](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=overpowering+smell%2C+overwhelming+smell&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coverpowering%20smell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coverwhelming%20smell%3B%2Cc0)*** (that overpowers (in various senses of the verb); overwhelming (OED)).

Comment: The OP used overpowering four times in his question.  He is asking for another word.

Comment: @ab2 - fair point. It is, however, the obvious word to me.  Asking for another word when there is a good one already seems unreasonable.

Comment: Plus one for using *overwhelming* three times.

Comment: I remain underwhelmed. :)

Comment: Removing my downvote because I agree that overpowering is the best word.

Answer (score 0):

*Anosmizing*, from *anosmia*, a medical term for loss of sense of smell, is perhaps analogous in strict meaning to *deafening*, but is hardly a common word. A more specific adjective like *nauseating* (a smell so bad it makes one feel sick) or *cloying* (an otherwise sweet or pleasant smell that is overwhelming) is probably the closest match, depending on the nature of the smell.